# warning C4180: qualifier applied to function type has no meaning; ignored

Tags: c++, visual-studio, warnings, constants, return-value

I've set up a compiler `/Za` option to disable lanquage extensions so that compiler uses strictly standard ISO C++.
Here is sample interface class for which I'm receiving following warning

> warning C4180: qualifier applied to function type has no meaning;
>   ignored

It is about const qualifier in return type of function, if I remove const, warning disapears but I don't wanna do that, neather I want to enable lanqage extenstions back.

My question is is: Is that warning reasonable?
If it is not then I'll use pragma to disable the warning but before that I would like to be sure that this warning is "false positive"

Because The following class is Correct ANSI ISO C++ Isn'it? so the warning should be disabled?

```
    class IBet
    {
    public:
        IBet() { };
        virtual ~IBet() = 0 { };
        virtual const float parentChips() const = 0; // Warning C4180
        virtual const short parentChilds() const = 0; // Warning C4180
            // ...
    };
```

Comment: The warning is valid in the sense that specifying a by-value return type as `const` has no meaning.  Whether or not it's valid ANSI C++, I'm not sure.

Comment: Changing the heading to make it easily searchable from SO and other search engines.

Comment: You are suggesting that this warning is *caused* by `/Za`. Does it actually disappear if you remove that switch?

Comment: "but I don't wanna do that" -- why not? What do you believe the `const` adds?

Comment: @jdv-Jan Yes it disapears if I enable language extensions back... Thanks hvd, thanks to David's explanation I understand this problem now better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return value of the two functions is declared as `const`. Since it is passed by value it has no meaning. You can remove that `const` since it serves absolutely no purpose.

Comment: Thank you David, can you or anybody confirm that using const in return by value is not correct ISO C++? I would like to know that to :)

Comment: Using a `const` return value is correct ISO C++ to the very best of my knowledge. However, since it is pointless, what you should do it remove it.

Comment: @codekiddy if it was not correct, the compiler would have to reject the code rather than warn you (I.e. error, nor warning). I don't believe in adding const there, some do, but I don't believe that the compiler should warn either (I.e. resolving that warning will not I prove the quality of the code or reduce the possibility of bugs)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Compilers are only very rarely required to reject code. A warning suffices for almost all cases where C++ requires a diagnostic.

Comment: I'd say the warning was good. Removing the `const` will improve the quality of the code. The reader of the code will be able to concentrate on what matters and not be distracted by the superfluous `const`.

Comment: @hvd: Can you provide just one example of something that is correct in the language and for which a diagnostic is required?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I have seen people recommending to always use `const` on a return statement that is by value to catch some (*absurd*) corner case like: `obj.getX().change(5);` in the case where `getX` returns a temporary, as that statement has no effect and seems to indicate an issue with the code. Again, I don't quite *buy* that use case, but I believe that warning should be used for constructs that are *correct* but *potentially unwanted*. I cannot think of a single scenario where the extra `const` there could cause an issue.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I cannot, and I don't believe there is (nor did I claim there is). What I said and meant is that even for obvious errors, such as `void f() { return 3; }`, while the standard requires a diagnostic, the standard doesn't require it to be an error. A compiler is free to emit a warning in its strictest conforming mode, and continue to accept the code.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas `const` isn't completely useless when applied to a class type function return type, but is for built-in types.

Comment: @hvd: The types are different, and that means that the functions are different, that is the effect in all cases. Now, consider: `struct base { virtual const int f() = 0; }; struct derived : base { int f() { return 1; } };`. If the `const` had no effect at all, then `derived::f` would be a valid override for `base::f`, which it is not. Again, I don't use the `const`, but why should the compiler complain when it is valid code? Note that while the top-level const-volatile qualifier is removed from the arguments to the function 8.3.5/4, the same does not apply to the return type

Comment: ... that is, `void f( int );` and `void f( const int );` declare exactly the same function, but `int f();` and `const int f();` declare two different functions (which in the same context would cause an error as you cannot have multiple functions with the same name and parameter-list and different return type) --this in turn also means that having both `int f( int );` and `const int f( const int );` is also an error, as the `const` in the parameter is removed by the compiler while the `const` in the return type is not.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas If the one use case of a `const int` return type is to override a virtual function with a `const int` return type, and that one use case can be trivially worked around by removing `const` from both functions, that's not much of a reason against the warning. "why should the compiler complain when it is valid code?" Compilers do that all the time, when the code is valid, but possibly or even probably a mistake. Why would you intentionally add `const`, knowing that it has no effect (other than to confuse others who do not know that it has no effect)?